# Rewrite the url of a website living in a subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently programming a website that, in a nutshell, loads its content dynamically via url parameters and php includes. The website is living under the root directory in a subfolder called "saischek".

The urls have one optional parameter: *page*, therefore the urls can for example look like this:

```
localhost/saischek/index.php?page=accounting
localhost/saischek/index.php
```

I would like to have that my urls look like this:

```
localhost/saischek/accounting
localhost/saischek/home <- if the url parameter _page_ isn't given
```

My .htaccess file is currently living in the subdirectory "saischek" and looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^saischek/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ saischek/index.php?page=$1
```

The website is running on apache webserver and all necessary changes in "httpd.conf" file are done and working.

Comment: So if only one of the two arguments is "declared" in the requesting URL `http://localhost/saischek/home`, then what should happen? How should the logic decide what is meant, a "folder" or a "page"?

Comment: The idea is that the index.php file is deciding based on the given two arguments "folder" and "file" which content it is loading into the html.
So if only "file" is declared, i have a include which searches in the "saischek" folder for that file and includes it.
If only "folder" is given, it looks for a folder in "saischek" and loads its index.php file.
If both are given, it loads the declared folders file.
And if "folder" and "file" isn't given, it loads a file called "home.php".
The code is working perfectly, only the rewrite to a nicer url isn't working.

Comment: You did not answer to my question...

Comment: Sorry, so i don't fully understand your question. What do you mean with "How should the logic decide what is meant, a "folder" or a "page"?". 
The logic is, as is a wrote, a php script which knows how to handle those two url-parameter "page" and "folder" and how to include the content into the html.

Comment: Your own description contains this: "`localhost/saischek/accounting` <- if only folder or page is declared"... So only _one_ of the two arguments is declared in the requesting URL: either the folder _or_ the page. From the syntax of the URL it is unclear which one it is. So how should a rewriting logic know that? Is "accounting" a folder or a page in your own example?

Comment: Oh ok now i understand what you mean. That is a really good question, i didn't thought before about that, but now i have rewritten my php script, and now there are only two options: eather no url-parameter is given, so it should rewrite to: `localhost/saischek/home`, or one parameter _page_ is given that should rewrite to: `localhost/saischek/$page` . Forget about the folder parameter.

Comment: I suggest you revise your question then :-)

Comment: I have revised my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say with the discussion in the comments to the question and your revision of the question you are nearly there, you found the solution yourself...

I would recommend to slightly change the main rule, also you will need to handle the "home" page you mentioned

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/saischek/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^/?saischek/home/?$ /saischek/index.php [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/?saischek/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /saischek/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,END]
```

I wonder however why you want to use the "home" slug at all, why not simply use `https://example.org/saischek` instead of `https://example.org/saischek/home`? In that case you would try this variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/saischek/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^/?saischek/?$ /saischek/index.php [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/?saischek/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /saischek/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding ? and changing + to * because in case the page is missing, the URL would not have them both.. (both / and page).

`^saischek/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$`